# maximal subtorus of a connected commutative algebraic linear group

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

I'm wondering the following:

> is the maximal subtorus of a connected commutative algebraic linear group over $k$
>   a) normal and closed b) defined over $k$ (for $k$ a field of characteristic zero, not necessarily algebraically closed)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is defined over $k$ for any $k$ (not even of char $0$). The result is due to Grothendieck, you can find this in SGA3 or also in Borels Linear Algebraic Groups book.